# Android - pass data to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

i try to get some data from MainActivity and show it in second activity i use putExtra but am still beginner and don't know so much about intents and data
in MainActivity i should insert my birth year and month then when i click at the button show me the result ,

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    }


 override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()


        getAGE.setOnClickListener {

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")


            val Get_year_input = age_year_input.text.toString().toInt()
            val getCurrentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
            val finish_year_input = Get_year_input - getCurrentYear
            val Get_month_input = age_month_input.text.toString().toInt()
            val getCurrentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
            val finish_month_input = age_month_input.text.toString().toInt() - getCurrentMonth

            // Send Data


            var i_month = Intent()
            i_month.putExtra("Month", finish_month_input)
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
            finish()

            var getintent = Intent("ahsb3omrk.show.result")


        }
    }

}
```

Second Activity :

```
class Second : AppCompatActivity() {

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)


    }


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {


    if (requestCode == 4 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

        var showintent = Intent(data!!.extras.getString("Month"))
        viewMonth.text = showintent.toString()
        viewDay.text = "Hello"
    }
}


}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i did !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setResult()` and `onActivityResult()` have nothing to do with this case.  
You pass the data to the intent:

```
val i_month = Intent(applicationContext, Second::class.java)
i_month.putExtra("Month", finish_month_input)
startActivity(i_month)
```

and in `Second` activity's `onCreate()`:

```
val finishMonthInput = intent.getIntExtra("Month", -1)
```

now in the `finishMonthInput` variable you will have the integer value passed, or `-1` if there was no value passed. 
Remove these lines from your code:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
............................
var getintent = Intent("ahsb3omrk.show.result")
```

and the whole `onActivityResult()` method from the `Second` class.

Comment: and to show data but still doesn't work

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: no data showing

Comment: Check in `onCreate()` after this line `val finishMonthInput = intent.getIntExtra("Month", -1)` the value of `finishMonthInput` if it is correct. If it is then you passed the value correctly, if not then you did something wrong. Also put this line `viewMonth.text = finishMonthInput.toString()` in `onCreate()` after you get the value of `finishMonthInput`.

Comment: it's work but why you used -1

Comment: It is the default value if no value is passed. So you check if it is -1 then there ws no extra value passed. I could use any other value but since we're dealing with a month value I thought that a negative number is a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data between activities, start the target activity 
using `startActivity(Intent)`.
With the Intent object having the data you want to send (use the `putExtra()` method).

In the second activity, access the data from the intent argument in the `onCreate()` method

[The developer website](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity) has an article on how to do all this.